# Android SQLLITE query to get Date Values within a Particular range

Tags: android, sqlite

I use this query to create a TABLE of transaction  in my Database :

```
String CREATE_TRANSITION_TABLE1 = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_TRANSITION_TWO + "(" + KEY_TRASITIONID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_AMOUNT_CREDIT + " DOUBLE,"
            + KEY_AMOUNT_DEBIT + " DOUBLE," + KEY_PURPOSE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PURPOSE1 + " TEXT," + KEY_PURPOSE2 + " TEXT," + KEY_DATE
            + " DATE," + KEY_BALANCE + " DOUBLE" + ")";
```

And this Query to Fetch all transaction from the Table :

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TRANSITION_ONE;
```

Now I would like to filter the result within a particular range of Date . 
Like :

```
StartDate : 2/1/2015 
 EndDate : 6/1/2015
```

I needed Query to do the Operation .. Need Immediate assistance .

Comment: How about `Between` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649709/how-to-select-data-between-two-date-range-in-android-sqlite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
SELECT * From  TABLE_NAME WHERE date_column BETWEEN  '"+StartDate+"' AND '"+EndDate+"';
```

Full Query :

```
"SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TRANSITION_ONE + " where " + KEY_DATE + " BETWEEN '2015-02-05' AND '2015-02-15';
```

Here, StartDate and EndDate are string variable.

But for this operation your date should be in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: String query= "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TRANSITION_ONE + " where " + KEY_DATE + " BETWEEN " + "2015-2-5" + " AND " + "2015-2-15";

Comment: @NafisDroid Change it to "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TRANSITION_ONE + " where " + KEY_DATE + " BETWEEN  '2015-02-05' AND '2015-02-15';