# Sqlite query for date range in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, date, date-range

I'm facing a problem while running a query which retrieves data from database for a given period of time.
The idea is that the user chooses 2 different dates (from , to) and then a ListView is populated with the data retrieved from a SQLite database - this data being between the `from` and `to` dates.
The query works perfectly without the `WHERE` clause, but when I try setting the date range, it fails.

I have stored the dates in SQLite in this format `M/d/yyyy 12:00:00 AM`.
While I send the dates (parameters) to the `SELECT` statement in this format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

I don't know how to deal with this.

Here is my code:

```
    public class ProductionCommentsActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private DBHandler dbHandler;
    private ListView listView;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    private EditText editTextFrom, editTextTo;
    private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialogFrom, datePickerDialogTo;
    private SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat;
    private String fromDate,toDate ; // variables to store the chosen dates


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_production_comments);



        dbHandler = new DBHandler(this, dbHandler.DATABASE_NAME_PRODUCTION, null, 1);
        try {
            dbHandler.copyDataBase();
            Log.d("copydb", dbHandler.getDatabaseName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("copydb",e.getMessage());
        }

        //defining list view
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        //defining edit texts properties
        editTextFrom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFrom);
        editTextFrom.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        editTextFrom.requestFocus();

        editTextTo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTo);
        editTextTo.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

        //setting up the date format
        simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
        setDateTimeField();
        context = this;
    }

    //method to handle the date pickers properties
    private void setDateTimeField() {
        editTextFrom.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) ProductionCommentsActivity.this);
        editTextTo.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) ProductionCommentsActivity.this);

        //creating a new instance of the calendar
        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        //creating a pop up date picker
        datePickerDialogFrom = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            //getting the chosen date and setting its format
            //and writing the chosen date in the edit text
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                editTextFrom.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(newDate.getTime()));
                fromDate = editTextFrom.getText().toString();
            }

        },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        datePickerDialogTo = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                editTextTo.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(newDate.getTime()));
                toDate = editTextTo.getText().toString();


            }

        },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }

    // on click method to handle which edit text was touched
    // and show the appropriate pop up calendar
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view == editTextFrom) {
            datePickerDialogFrom.show();
        } else if(view == editTextTo) {
            datePickerDialogTo.show();
        }
    }

    public void searchDates(View view){
        setDateTimeField();
        try {
           // getProductionComments(fromDate, toDate);
            getProductionComments(fromDate,toDate);

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }

    //get production comments data
    private void getProductionComments(String from, String to) {
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getReadableDatabase();


            String query = "SELECT Date,Item,Comments FROM ProductionCommentData WHERE Date BETWEEN "+ from +
                    "AND "+ to+";";
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Date"));
                        String item = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Item"));
                        String comments = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Comments"));

                        results.add("Date: " + date.substring(0, 9) + newline + newline  +
                                "Item: " + item + newline + newline  + "Comments: " + comments);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLiteException se){
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error retrieving data from database");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `I have dates stored in sqlite database file in this format M/d/yyyy 12:00:00 AM` But did you read this? [SQLite TimeStrings](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Answer (score 2):

You should store your Date as long value in database. Simple `new Date().getTime()` gives you this value and `new Date(long value)` returns it back. So you can make such queries easy.

Comment: It's not necessary. Using the proper [SQLite TimeString](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) is easier.

Comment: I have good news for you: **no string comparison is needed**. Just use the SQLite date functions and/or the BETWEEN clause. Hope you learned something new.

Comment: @ViktorYakunin `long` data type doesn't exist in sqlite! what do you mean by "long value" ?

Comment: @user3804193 He means INTEGER, I guess.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein how many data types are in sqlite? 4 - int, real, blob, text. All the rest are converted to text. So, it is not clear, but using int type to store your date and compare it to Date.getTime() gives you much better performance than to store SimpleDateFormat, convert your Date to String and perform Between which is String comparison operation.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein what do you think i should do? what do you suggest?

Comment: @user3804193 Something like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9649747/2649012

Comment: @user3804193 long type for Java code and int for sqlite http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672473/is-there-type-long-in-android-sql

Comment: @ViktorYakunin I don't find a **number of milliseconds** representing a date being very **human friendly**. But something like this is: `SELECT * FROM Categories WHERE DateCreated BETWEEN '2012-03-11 00:00:00' AND '2015-05-12 23:59:59'`

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Agree it is not friendly, but if your column name is something like 'timestamp' or 'eventDate' it is more clear what the number means. Your solution is working no doubts - post it as answer and I will vote for it :)

Answer (score 1):

What I can suggest is to:

- Export your table to CSV,
- Change the date values to a proper [SQLite TimeString](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) and
- Re-import the CSV after deleting the original table.

Then, you can run a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM Categories WHERE DateCreated BETWEEN '2012-03-11 00:00:00' AND '2015-05-12 23:59:59'
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9649747/2649012), which is better, because it uses **bound parameters**.