# Android SQLite Query between Dates not working

Tags: android, sqlite

I have to get all records count from table. My Approach is as follows:

```
  public int getTasksByStatusIDBetweenDates(int statusID, String startDate, String endDate) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
            "select * from Task" +
                    " where StatusID=" + statusID + " and AssignDate between '" + startDate + "' and '" + endDate + "'", null);

    int total = 0;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        total = cursor.getInt(0);

    cursor.close();
    return total;
}
```

Currently it is returning me 0. My date format is **"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"**

Please guide me where i am doing wrong. Thanks !

Comment: Where are you calling this method?Can you post the code thatI mentioned?

Comment: @noman-hamid : is the date format stored in your db is same as the date format of your arguement startDate and endDate ???

Comment: @AntónioPaulo  i am just getting count from that function into and integer variable in my activity. But the count i am getting from this query is 0.

Comment: `cursor.getInt(0)`, are you going to get first column value of the table??

Comment: I guess you should wrap time string variables with `datetime()` function

Comment: `cursor.getCount()` return the same. total effected rows

Comment: what is the col format ? is it just date? or timestamp ?

Comment: I just want to know if start and enddate are empty or not. Maybe that's why it returns 0.

Comment: @AntónioPaulo  AssignDate is text in my table. I have to convert it into DATETIME to use my query ?

Comment: @BasilBattikhi  my col format for AssignDate is text

Comment: @AntónioPaulo  both dates are not empty.

Comment: what is data type of your date column ?

Comment: @SanjayKakadiya  its TEXT

Comment: make it DATETIME, then its works.

Comment: @SanjayKakadiya  for that i have to change my parsing schema also?

Comment: there is no any other way to do this.

Comment: @SanjayKakadiya  No.. we can store timestamp value as TEXT in sqlite.
See this link:
http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: sure you can but you can't use the between function in mysql if the col is a text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or to existing code just call `cursor.getCount();`
`total=cursor.getCount();`

> **Cursor.getCount();** 
>   Returns the numbers of rows in the cursor.

**UPDATED**
Query to get records b/w two date [SO - How to select data between two date range in android SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9649747/2032561)

Query is
`SELECT * FROM mytab where my_date BETWEEN '2016-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-03-19 00:00:00'`

Comment: Yes i tried that. Tell me 1 thing, i am using AssigneDate datatype as Text in table.. is it ok OR i have to use DATETIME data type ?

Comment: well for me TEXT type is working fine.. however try with DateTime also.

Comment: Cool.. can you share your full function ?

Comment: Thanks i will try that.. i have to show in grid view ... records are for all months so i have to apply filters accordingly.. That is why i am passing date in query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109809/discussion-between-skadoosh-and-noman-hamid).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using COUNT(*) instead of just *.

Try this.

```
public int getTasksByStatusIDBetweenDates(int statusID, String startDate, String endDate) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
            "select count(*) from Task" +
                    " where StatusID=" + statusID + " and AssignDate between '" + startDate + "' and '" + endDate + "'", null);

    int total = 0;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        total = cursor.getInt(0);

    cursor.close();
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A query with `SELECT *` returns all columns of all rows of the table.

`cursor.getInt(0)` returns the value of the first column of the current row of the cursor.

To count rows, you could use a query with `SELECT COUNT(*) ...`, and read the value returned by that. Alternatively, use a helpful [helper function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29) that constructs the query for you:

```java
public int getTasksByStatusIDBetweenDates(int statusID, String startDate, String endDate) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(
            db, "Task",
            "StatusID=" + statusID + " and AssignDate between ? and ?",
            new String[]{ startDate, endDate });
}
```

Comment: Tried that.. Not working.. AssignedDate in my table is text.