# How to filter/sort view based on date range in android using java?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, date-range

[image]

```
    else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.sort_by_unprofitable_trades){
        Collections.sort(notesList, Model.UnProfitableTrades);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.sort_by_date_range){
        materialDatePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Tag_picker");
        materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new 
        MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener<Pair<Long, Long>>() {
            @Override
            public void onPositiveButtonClick(Pair<Long,Long> selection) {
                Long selctedstartDate = selection.first;
                Long selectedendDate = selection.second;
                startDateString = DateFormat.format("yyyy/MM/dd", new 
                Date(selctedstartDate)).toString();
                endDateString = DateFormat.format("yyyy/MM/dd", new 
                 Date(selectedendDate)).toString();
                //Collections.sort(notesList, Model.SortByDaterange);
                sortByDateRange();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

DataBase class:- void sortbyDateRange(String startDate, String endDate){
SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TableName + " WHERE " + ColumnTradeDate + " BETWEEN " +
startDate + " AND " + endDate ;
database.execSQL(query);
}

In Database Inspector the SQL query is giving correct results but no change is happening in the recycler view. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

between query doesn't support any string value. Because in string value comparison not possible so you need to do the operation with float, Int and long type data .. I have  faced the same problem then I converted my date to in long type data by using calender.timeInMillis .if u do like that you have to make a column in your table long type than send in to your database then do between query

pick your date and convert it to long type

```
   val datepickerdialog =
            DatePickerDialog(requireContext(), { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->

                
                srchDate2_id.text = "$dayOfMonth-$month-$year"

                calender2 = Calendar.getInstance()
                calender2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
                calender2.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
                calender2.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)


                dt2 = calender2 .timeInMillis// send it to database you can do the between query with this value 
                Log.d(TAG, "first time: $dt2")
              

            }, y, m, d)

        datepickerdialog.show()
    }
```

still problem comment below.

Comment: Hi Mahmud, I found out that we can use BETWEEN operator on the text, see examples https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp . Attaching Screenshot of the database inspector the query in the code above gives out correct results

Comment: Can't upload screenshot due to less reputation but this query works : SELECT * FROM mynotes WHERE tradeDate BETWEEN "2022/01/01" AND "2022/02/13" ,Here all dates are in string format and even the column tradeDate is of type string.

Comment: sql , mysql, oracle ,  sqlite all are similar but not same .. I have tried with date type data too but failed .. than I did it with long type data because in some app you will see months are show like 2022/Feb/13 or 13-02-2022 you will face again another problem because sqlite doesn't support those format https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_date_time.htm .. I think with this raw system you wont face bugs.. as I have tried convert to millisecond will be best try.

Comment: if you still want to try with string then see those answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649709/how-to-select-data-between-two-date-range-in-android-sqlite